# How to remove Set, which is used as value, from ConcurrentHashMap<String, Set<String>>?

Tags: java, concurrency, race-condition, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

Let's consider the following following code:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Set<String>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

// Add element: {mapKey, setValue}

map.computeIfAbsent(mapKey, new Function<String, Set<String>>() {
    @Override
    public Set<String> apply(String mapK) {
        return ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    }
}).add(setValue);

// Remove element: {mapKey, setValue}

Set<String> updatedSet = map.computeIfPresent(mapKey, new BiFunction<String, Set<String>, Set<String>>() {
    @Override
    public Set<String> apply(String mapK, Set<String> old) {
        old.remove(setValue);
        return old;
    }
});

// I need remove mapKey, but I cannod do this like this, because of race condition bug
if (updatedSet.isEmpty()) {
    map.remove(mapKey);
}
```

So, what we can see:

1. We have `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Set<String>>` map, where `key` of map is `String`, and `value` is `ConcurrentHashSet`.
2. I need to remove `set`, which is value of `map`, when `set` is `empty`.
3. I cannot implement naive removing of `set`, because of race condition bug.

Is there any brilliant solution of my problem?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635292/high-performance-concurrent-multimap-java-scala

Comment: @dnault thank you.

Comment: As a side note, since you’re obviously using Java 8, you can use lambda expressions for these functions.

Comment: @Holger yea, thank you . I thought, that this code is more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`computeIfPresent` removes the entry if the mapper returns `null`. Instead of performing the removal in a separate step, return `null` from the mapper if you want to remove the entry.

(Also, you should really fold the `.add(setValue)` into your `computeIfAbsent` mapper, and use `compute` instead of `computeIfAbsent`, because you're not doing anything to protect the `add` call right now. Using `merge` would also be an option.)